# How to show comments when filtering for docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-image

The goal of our team is to have about a dozen of docker images ready for testing purposes with various testing scenarios. In order to ease choosing we directly want to attach information about the scenarios to the images. I have identified adding labels and comments while committing containers as solutions to this problem using `docker commit --message/--change`. However, now I have the problem that docker does not seem to allow the display of the `COMMENT` column outside of the `docker history` command. My desired approach is to use

```
docker images --filter "label=product_version_full=X.X.X"
```

in order to list docker images suitable to test our team's version "X.X.X". While that is working fine I do not get enlightened with the comments that I had added previously to the images in the resulting table.

I have already spent some time on the internet looking for the solution but could find it neither here nor elsewhere. Has anyone already come across it? 

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately docker image listing does not support pretty printing of labels. Ubuntu `docker-image-ls` man page has the best documentation on the [currently supported placeholders](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/docker-image-ls.1.html).

Docker inspect might be useful but it shows huge amount of information for the image: (see Labels, that is the part you are interested of)

```
$ docker inspect 1bfebeeed10f
        .....clip
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c"
        ],
        "OnBuild": [],
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": "Softagram <no-reply@softagram.com>"
        ....clip..
```

Single Label key value can be extracted this way:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{index .Config.Labels "maintainer"}}' 1bfebeeed10f

Softagram <no-reply@softagram.com>
```

The `-q` argument of `docker images` makes it good for chaining with xargs:

```
 docker images -q |xargs docker inspect --format='{{ .Config.Image }} {{.Config.Labels.maintainer}}'
```

In case you need to get all the labels, at once you may drop ".maintainer" out, so using `{{.Config.Labels}}` instead.

Combining Python scripts with Docker makes it very easy and maintainable:

```
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> for image in client.images.list():
...     print(image.labels)
... 
{'maintainer': 'Softagram <no-reply@softagram.com>'}
{'maintainer': 'Softagram <no-reply@softagram.com>'}
{'maintainer': 'Softagram <no-reply@softagram.com>'}
...clip
```

Using Python will make automation smooth, read more about it [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a format and filter the getted result like that by filtring using image name or image tag :

```sh
docker images --format "{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}"
```

to get the list of images after that ,

```sh
docker images --format "{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}" | grep <your-image-tag>
```

I hope that my idea can help you to resolve your issue.